# How to check if the save button is clicked on download dialog box using PHP?

Tags: php, download

There are some files on my site that users can download them. I use PHP header() to read the files and show download dialog to users.

I have to increase the download count. So I need to detect if the file is really downloaded.

May be a way is to know if the user clicks save or cancel button or some approach using PHP on the server.

Would you help me on this issue? how can I check if the save button is clicked or not?

Comment: you can create a download count based on how many times the url of the file is accessed with download request headers. You can't detect if the file is completely downloaded because its already on the side of the browser, except I think if you are using flash or java applet

Answer (score 2):

You can only detect the initial request. You can not detect whether the file successfully downloaded or not.

Based on this, you would need to implement a count logic when you generate the download; at a similar location where you make the header() call.

edit: you could track the session/remote ip of the user and ignore subsequent requests to the file within a specific timeframe:

Comment: but is it fare to count the click on download link? when no real download may happen?

Answer (score 1):

`You can not detect whether the file successfully downloaded or not` as per answer you have received...because what if user has closed your website? then you no longer attached with user browser activity. So it is not possible to track whether file is downloaded.

Yes you can add counter same as visit counter using session as you have seen many example on website while starting learning about session in php.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben Rowe's answer sums it up.

You could use a CDN like [Amazon's Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) if you're concerned about bandwidth limitations. It's free for the first year too